# JRuby on Rails does not work with Tomcat running as a service on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, jruby, tomcat6, ruby-on-rails-3, warbler

### Problem

It seems like running Tomcat as a service doesn't play well with Rails 3 applications that are packaged up using warble. Looking at the log files, it looks like there is either a circular dependency or a dependency that is being dynamically resolved but cannot be found, so it loops. Eventually, `org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: stack level too deep` is thrown. However, when I use `startup.bat` to start Tomcat instead, this problem does not occur.

Any help would be appreciated! I've been desperately searching for answer to this. Thanks in advance!

#### Deployment Platform

- Windows Server 2008 (64-bit)
- Apache Tomcat 6.29 (64-bit)
- JDK 1.6
- Rails 3
- jruby 1.5.6
- warbler (1.2.1)
- jruby-jars (>= 1.4.0)
- jruby-rack (>= 1.0.0)

#### Tomcat localhost.log

http://pastie.org/1308566

Comment: Can you try updating Bundler and trying again?

Comment: I'll give it a shot tomorrow as soon as I get to work. Thanks Nick! I really appreciate hearing back from you.

Comment: Hey Nick, I'm running Bundler 1.0.7. Still seeing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess your database connection information contains an unexpected null string, which the system is attempting to convert to uppercase somewhere. See this error message as the hint:

> at
>   ERB.result(C:/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/rails3app/WEB-INF/gems/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:86)
>     at
>   Rails::Application::Configuration.database_configuration(C:/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/rails3app/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:58)

This may be correctable with a configuration edit.

Comment: Look at the database configuration - if it makes sense to have empty or missing data for some of the fields, try replacing them with the empty string ("") or equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. That resolved the new issue, but now I'm back to the original problem. :S

Answer (score 1):

I just posted the following on your Jruby ticket [http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-5237]:

This is actually a problem with the version of procrun (Apache Commons Daemon) that ships with Tomcat <= 6.0.29. You need to upgrade either the entire Tomcat 6 install or the version of procrun you're using. Procrun needs to be >= 1.0.4

Tomcat 6 upgrade: http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi

I was having this exact same problem and the upgrade solved it for me.

I've posted over at http://techblog.amphora-research.com/2011/03/tomcat-6-stack-level-too-deep-error-on-windows/ if you're interested in the details.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Look through your startup.bat configuration. It may be that Tomcat is started with a higher memory setting for Java through there, allowing the recursion to finish without running out of memory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but running out of memory is a result of Bundler's inability to find the appropriate resource.

Comment: Maybe it's a matter of environment variables then? The service may be starting with the wrong settings. If you look through the bat file and check the settings, you could reset the service to use the same one (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/windows-service-howto.html)